# Is it possible to insert in-line javascript code into another javascript/jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, append, inline-code

This question looks a little dumb... but I am wondering if is it possible to insert in-line javascript code into another javascript code. Lets put this clear:

I'm trying to put a google plus button, appending it through jquery as follows:

```
jQuery('.gplus').append('<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>');
```

This button needs external js in order to work properly. What i'm trying to do is insert the external js doing this:

```
var gplusjs = '
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {var po = document.createElement("script");
    po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;
    po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>';
jQuery('#js').append(gplusjs);
```

The result of this is the code printed as HTML, but not interpreted as a script.
This is possible? I am a dumbass? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

That's because jQuery append and scripts don't work. Do it the old fashioned way

```
var gplusjs = '(function() {var po = document.createElement("script");po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);})();';
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = gplusjs;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Also note that multi line string literals don't exist in JS.

Comment: Actually, you can create multi-line string literals by escaping each newline with a `\​`

Comment: @SLaks that's not a multi line string literal, that's a dirty hack with escaping the new line character.

Comment: @SLaks as a further aside it's invalid ES3, do you happen to know whether ES5 allows it?

Comment: @Raynos - backslash + newline as line-continuation is in the [ECMAScript 262 5th Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You should just execute that code normally:

```
var po = document.createElement("script");
po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;
po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
```

Or, even easier:

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
```